# Moved files from remote server using my root account. Can't edit files with my other admin accounts

Tags: unix, command

I transferred files with `scp` using my `root` account since it wouldn't let me with my other admin account `warren`. I tried editing files remotely as well with my `warren` account, but can't, it only works with `root`. Why is that? How can I change it?

Comment: an sftp/scp/ssh server which allows remote-root is NOT a good idea...

Comment: Can you expand on that? I used SCP on one server: `scp root@myserver:/path` then it asked me to login and that was that. What's wrong with it?

Comment: it's a security risk to allow direct login access to the root account.

Comment: What can I do to prevent it or secure myself?

Comment: there's an option in sshd.conf (the server conf, not client) to disable remote root logins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in root use chown to change the owner of the files to warren.

```
 chown warren /path/tofiles
```

Comment: you may want to do chown -R warren /path/tofiles to do it recursively

Comment: I use my `warren` account for pretty much everything. I have all my websites hosted in a directory `/home/warren/public/<sites>`. Should I just do `chown -R warren /home/warren/public` ?

Comment: If it worked out, please select this as the correct answer, cause it makes me feel special ;)